# Evitar aparición de popup de "Guardar credenciales" en safari (macOS)

Tags: reactjs, formularios, ios, chrome, safari

Estoy tratando de evitar que aparezca la solicitud de credenciales nativas del navegador. Tengo un flujo de registro con 3 pantallas diferentes, en la primera el usuario debe ingresar nombre, apellido, correo electrónico y contraseña. En esta pantalla tengo el formulario con los diferentes inputs, y solo la contraseña tiene "type=password":

```html
<form autocapitalize="none">
    <input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="given-name" id="firstName" type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input makeStyles-     input-114 makeStyles-input-119" autocapitalize="words" value="">

    <input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="family-name" id="lastName" type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input makeStyles-     input-114 makeStyles-input-123" autocapitalize="words" value="">

    <input aria-invalid="false" id="birthdate" type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input makeStyles-input-114 makeStyles-        input-127" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" value="">

    <input aria-invalid="false" id="mobile" type="tel" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input makeStyles-input-114 makeStyles-input-131     MuiInputBase-inputAdornedStart" autocapitalize="words" value="+63 ">

    <input aria-invalid="true" autocomplete="new-password" id="newPassword" type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input            makeStyles-input-114 makeStyles-input-135 password" autocapitalize="words" value="">
</form>

<button type="button" style="width: 160px;">Next</button>
```

Cuando presiono el botón "Next", va a la siguiente pantalla, y se muestra el mensaje de credencial. En este punto el formulario no se envía, y no hay ninguna llamada de red cuando clicko el botón "Next".

Para Chrome, he cambiado el type="password" por el "text" y he implementado la class "password" que oculta los caracteres del input mediante la propiedad css webkit-text-security: disk:

```html
.password {
  -webkit-text-security: disc;
  -moz-text-security: disc;
}
```

pero esta solución no funciona para firefox ni Safari en iOS ni macOS. Firefox no utiliza webkit y no tiene ninguna propiedad similar; a su vez Safari reconoce un input de tipo "password" no solo por el susodicho type="password", si no también por esa propiedad css -webkit-text-security: disk, por lo que el navegador aún muestra el popup de credenciales.

Comment: Bienvenido a es.StackOverflow. Te recomiendo que edites la pregunta y la traduzcas al castellano para que podamos ayudarte.

Welcome to es.StackOverlow. I recommend you to to edit the question and translate the body to Spanish, so we could help you.

Comment: Puedes agregar el atributo `textContentType = none` en el input? https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#textcontenttype

Comment: No es una app en react Native, es reactjs en web